# .htaccess redirection (php) - multiple link "layers" need redirecting (pagination of categories)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm in a bit of a conundrum. I have some pagination code that works great - but I need to paginate both the index page, pages by category, and the search results. So - index.php, categories.php and search.php.

```
my php/html code is this:
<a href="/page/1" class="button">First</a>
<a href="<?php if($pagenr <= 1){ echo '/#'; } else { echo "/page/".($pagenr - 1); } ?>" class="button">Prev</a>
<a href="<?php if($pagenr >= $totalPages){ echo '/#'; } else { echo "/page/".($pagenr + 1); } ?>" class="button">Next</a>
<a href="/page/<?php echo $totalPages; ?>" class="button">Last</a>
```

and my .htaccess redirect is this:

```
Rewriterule ^page/([^/.]+)?$ /?pagenr=$1 [L]
```

Which works FINE, but only for the index pagination. I'm sure it's because the category page is redirected (`RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)?$ /showCategory?category=$1 [L]`) and the search page is just domain.com/search - no rewriting there other than removing .php extension.

So - the question is, how can I get the redirection working for the category page and search results pagination as well?

Comment: So what do your actual pagination URLs for a category look like? Give an example.

Comment: @CBroe right now on my page they're showing up as https://example.com/page/2 (just like the ones for the index page), but I want them to be https://example.com/category/CategoryName/page/2 - without pagination it's https://example.com/category/CategoryName already

Comment: _That_ part has nothing to do with mod_rewrite in the first place; creating the correct pretty URLs in your HTML output, is something you need to do yourself.

Comment: @CBroe - agreed - but can you see where I went wrong?

Comment: Well what does a `/` at the start of a relative URL mean?

Comment: @CBroe - yup missed that one - but that means I'm approaching the links wrong. Removing the / only gives me the correct link the first time - then it just appends endlessly... Unless I use a different pagination for index, categories and search, which i was hoping to avoid.

Comment: _“Removing the / only gives me the correct link the first time - then it just appends endlessly”_ - of course, because when you visit the first pagination page, you are on `http://example.com/foo/page/2` already - combining that base URL with the relative URL `page/3` now, of course leads to `http://example.com/foo/page/2/page/3`. You will need to create these pagination links somewhat dynamically, there is no way around that.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well. Time to brush off my JavaScript I think - Thanks for your help @Cbroe

Comment: Why JS? Just insert a variable as path prefix, and _set_ that variable according to what page you are on, before the pagination.

Comment: @CBroe I can see now I'm going to have to look at this more systematically from the ground up - the .htaccess needs to be modified too -  example.com/category/Categoryname/page/2 is what I need, but I'm getting a 404 (of course) - and I need example.com/search to be it's own "directory" instead of just a name without the extension so I can do example.com/search/page/2. Pretty links are great, but geesh they make my brain itch sometimes